# python remove non tags in xml

Tags: python, regex, xml

I want to remove all content, which is not in xml tags (cleanup) and optionally put it in a list. I got some xml like this:

```
<tag>some text</tag> unwanted text <tag>some text</tag>
```

and I want to get this with python (regex)

```
('<tag>some text</tag>','<tag>some text</tag>')
```

I tried it with:

```
cleanup = re.findall(r"^<.>.*</.>$",  input)
```

but I think the whole input matches also the regex how can i fix this ?

Update1:

i try to load it with

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(str(cleanup))
```

Comment: yeah i would but i get an error , i update my question

Comment: ah ok I see what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just want to extend what have been already answered here, because I think the correct way is *NOT* using regex to handle xml-like content. You should use a XML parser, and the **unwanted** content is called **tail**, which you can *CLEAN* while parsing, this is one way of doing it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

s = '''<root><tag>some text</tag> unwanted text <tag>some text</tag></root>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(s)

cleaned_tree = []

for node in tree:
    node.tail = ''
    cleaned_tree.append(ET.tostring(node))

print cleaned_tree # or print(cleaned_tree) if Python 3
['<tag>some text</tag>', '<tag>some text</tag>']
```

As a side note: you may look at your **str(cleanup)** and see it has missing tags like **root** in my sample. It fails **fromstring()** may hint something is wrong with your xml source.

Comment: @fuubah, glad it helps. Should you nodes contain any nested tags, though you will need to iterate and handle them properly, but I believe **tail** attribute is what you're looking for.

Comment: okay, the only change I made was the print (cleaned_tree) for python 3

Comment: @fuubah, cool I never really asked what version of Python you're on :) I've updated accordingly